# Process perl script On POST method in Django

Tags: html, django, perl

I am newbie ,am trying to process perl script on submit button in HTML in Django framework.I will try to be clean and clear what i wann do, Apologies for my English language.

I have build simple registration website using Django framework.In that instead of using Django auth, i want to call perl script and process the new user registration form.

I have written code for simple new user registration form and perl script which takes data from HTML and splits that data and send it to back-end for further process.I successfully accomplished this task using CGI server.

This process i want to call in Django framework .How can I do this .I tried to do it with subprocess but Am not getting solution for this .

Thank You
Pervez

Comment: Why not stick with Django/Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you would want to do that, but you can run the perl script as a system command, like:

```
import commands
commands.getstatusoutput('perl /path/to/script.pl arguments')
```

Answer (score 1):

run your perl script as cgi, post registration form to the script

```
<form action="your-perl-script.cgi" method="POST">
...
</form>
```